# What is the correct way to return interface pointer from out-of-process COM server?

Tags: c++, com, atl

I have a out-of-proc COM server which has two ATL COM objects . object1 exposes an interface which internally creates object2 and returns an interface pointer to it in following way:

```
HRESULT CObject1::CreateObject2(IObject2** pIobj2)
{
    CComObject<Object2>* pObj = NULL;

    HRESULT hr = CComObject<Object2>::CreateInstance(&pObj);

    hr = pObj->QueryInterface(IID_IObject2,(void**)pIobj2);

    //Some reason i need to store this pIobj2
    (*pIobj2)->AddRef();

    return hr;
}
```

Object1 exposes another interface to remove object2

```
HRESULT CObject1::RemoveObject2(IObject2* pIobj2)
{
    pIobj2->Release(); //This to compensate QI done in CreateObject2

    pIobj2->Release(); //This to compensate addref done to store in create
}
```

My requirement is that the client should not call Release on the `IObject2` pointer anywhere after `IObject1::CreateObject2()`. To destroy object2 it should call `IObject1::RemoveObject2()`.When I execute the client, after RemoveObject2, object2 is not destroyed, however when I call release on the Iobject2 pointer in client after RemoveObject2 , the object2 gets destroyed.

Comment: This is not okay.  There's still a proxy on the client side that has a non-zero ref count.  You cannot make this work in a reliable way beyond notifying the client through an event that it should call Release().

Comment: @HansPassant: Thank you for the reply. So in other words the refcount at client side is different from the refcount which is present at server side and Client has to call release always irrespective whether  server is managing its own refcount. Please let me know if my understanding is correct. Thank you again.

Answer (score 2):

Life cycle management in out of process COM object is much more complex than in-proc. For example, the system has to take into account that the other party may die (for example, the server should clean up resources allocated for an object, if the client process has died without a Release). For this Microsoft has a DCOM garbage collection.

There are indeed two COM objects, on the client (proxy) and on the server (stub). The proxy maintains its own reference count, and your code confuses this reference count, since you release a reference count of object 2 on the server - information that will not get to the client.

I strongly encourage you to change your architecture. For one, the COM contract is that the way to release object is with the Release method. That's the contract, and your design changes it, and this is why you get DCOM confused.

I think a better design would be:

1. In Object2 keep a reference to Object1 (say, m_pobj1)
2. Do NOT have Object1::RemoveObject2. Instead have a private (non COM) CleanupObject2, if you need to do some work.
3. Implement Object2::FinalRelease (the cleanup method of Object2), and call m_pobj1->Cleanup[Object2(this)
4. Remember, that if you need to keep pointers to obj2 within obj1, make sure these are *weak* references. That is - just pointers - without adding a reference count.

Clients call Object1::CreateObject2 and get a reference to obj2. When they are done, they will call obj2->Release(), and will clear the reference count, and call obj1->CleanupObject2 method.

Comment: Thanks a lot.This helped to shed some light on my COM understanding.